# Joomla HTTP 500 error on deploying to remote site

Tags: joomla

I am a beginner at Joomla and may have probably missed out some key details when trying to deploy...:

Basically, I had uploaded the local Joomla project onto a remote host on a subdirectory. Eg: www.website.com/joomla.

However, I can't access any of the pages that resides in the joomla folder. Even creating a dummy html page, I can't get past the HTTP 500 error. Even trying Xenu to crawl the folder for any broken links shows server error 500 right away. It can't get into joomla folder. Any clues on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check, rename or remove the .htaccess file after uploading the website ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check apache / nginx logs, --- mostly the error and access log. You could check there if it is fetching the right files from the right remote static directory.

In debian apache the access and error logs are stored in /var/log/apache. Check your httpd.conf for the right directory on which it were -- dumping the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Just converting my comment to an answer:

- Check your .htaccess file.
- Rename it or delete it if you don't want to check it.